# TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am trying to integrate select2 in my html template but i keep getting this error. i want to be able to select multiple options at a time
i am not sure how to go about it.
help would be appreciated.

admin.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Select2OptionData } from 'ng2-select2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  public candidateData: Array<Select2OptionData>;
  public options: Select2Options;
  public value: string[];
  public current: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { this.candidateData = [
    { id: '1', text: 'Mohammadu Buhari' },
    { id: '2', text: 'Atiku Abubakr' },
    { id: '3', text: 'John Doe'},
    { id: '4', text: 'Someone Else'}];

    this.options = {
      multiple: true
    };

    this.current = this.value.join(' | ');
  }

  changed(data: {value: string[]}) {
    this.current = data.value.join(' | ');
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <label>Candidates</label>
      <select2 
      [data] = "exampleData"
      [options] = "options"
      [width] = "500"
      [value] = "value"
      (valueChanged) = "changed($event)"
      ></select2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Init the value `public value: string[] = []`.

Comment: i see. but after i init the model, the error goes away but i still cannot select multiple

Comment: [Check this working code here..almost same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963048/multiple-select-dropdown-using-angular-with-input-tag)

Comment: I suggest providing a link to the library you are using, update the code to what it looks like right now, update the question title and add a question marked question at the end of your post :).

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your model because it's `undefined` when you try to access it in `ngOnInit`.

```
public value: string[] = [];
```

Comment: i see. but after i init the model, the error goes away but i still cannot select multiple

Comment: Change `[data] = "exampleData"` to `[data] = "candidateData"`